# Join tables to feature class

Tags: arcpy, csv, attribute-joins, loop

I have a problem I'm trying to solve. 
I want to join serval CSV files to a feature class, I would like to create one new feature class for each CSV files. If it's possible each fc would be named after the CSV file used.

For example if I have:
abc.csv and zxy.csv I want to feature class to be named , with each fc corresponding to one of the csv file, abc and zxy.

```
inFeatures = r"path to my feature class"
layerName = "fc_layer"
joinTables = r"path to the folder where my CSV files are"
joinFieldlyr = "CI_INT"
joinFieldtab = "CI"
outFeature = r"path to the folder dataset where I want my feature class"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inFeatures, layerName)
arcpy.AddJoin_management(layerName, joinFieldlyr, joinTables, joinFieldtab)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(layerName, outFeature)
```

That code work perfectly for one file but I can't get the name part right. I tried to use os.path.join and os.path.splitext so I can find and use the name of my files but without any succes. 
I also tried to code a loop to iterate trough my folder so I don't have to do it manually.

Comment: So you have a feature class and want to join csv1 and then export, remove join and join csv2 and export etc..? Did it work the first time without creating a table view of the csv?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import arcpy, os
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=1

#Change to match your data
arcpy.env.workspace='C:\filegeodatabase.gdb'
inFeatures='polygon12345'
csvfolder=r'C:\csvfolder'

#Find all csv files in csvfolder and add to csvlist
csvlist=[]
for file in os.listdir(csvfolder):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        csvlist.append(os.path.join(csvfolder, file))

#For each csv in csvlist join and export
for csv in csvlist:
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features=inFeatures, out_layer='fclyr')
    arcpy.MakeTableView_management(in_table=csv, out_view='csvview')
    arcpy.AddJoin_management(in_layer_or_view='fclyr', in_field='CI_INT', join_table='csvview', join_field='CI')
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(in_features='fclyr',out_feature_class=os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(csv))[0])
```

If you have whitespaces in the csv name you can use [str.replace()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) to remove them. Last line of code will then be:

```
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(in_features='fclyr',out_feature_class=os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(csv))[0].replace(" ","")
```

Comment: What if you're using forward slashes? Use the module designed for path manipulation: `os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(csv))[0]`

Comment: What I don't understand is that if do print os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(csv))[0] I get the correct name but in the loop it ends up not working.

Comment: Thank you for your answers (@Paul @Bera) but your code didn't work due to the way my csv files are named. The loop works for the GIS stuff but not for the rest. I think part of the problem is that my files are full of white-spaces. For example I have one file named "ABC Region1 City 1" and  "ABC Region1 City 2" and the script ends up giving me an error message "arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output 'C:\filegeodatabase.gdb'\ABC Region1 City 2 Failed to execute (CopyFeatures)."

Comment: @VictorA can't use spaces in FGDB. Use [ValidateTableName](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/validatetablename.htm).

Comment: @Paul: Your way is better, i have changed the code!